# How to make function atomically?

Tags: locking, mutex, semaphore

I am now practicing lock,semaphore,mutual exclusive ..

I trying to implements simple code such that add 1 iteratively using mutex.

And here is my code.

[A.c]

```
for(int i=0; i<1000;i++){ 
   acquire(&lock);
   ADD1("count.txt"); // count.txt is shared memory 
   temp=Load("count.txt") // Load func get number
   printf("\n %d",temp);
   release(&lock);
}
```

also there is [B.c] all the same with A.

And I compiled A.c and B.c

```
gcc A.c -o A
gcc B.c -o B
```

and execute

```
./A & ./B
```

what I expected is ascending printing such as

```
1
2
3
4
..
1999
2000
```

But there is problem, it correctly count until 2000

but.. it was not ascending order..

```
4
5
6
7
1
...
234
235
...
223
...
1999
2000
```

Think this is weird because If I can see '2000' then It means mutex lock does work!

But why printing log is not ascending order..?

p.s/ sorry for if you can't understanding well...
     Since I used google  translation, my bad